# How to extract only the routes from vue router to generate sitemap

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-router, sitemap

I have a file exporting my VueRouter instance:

```
// src/js/router.js

import VueRouter from "vue-router";

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      name: "home",
      path: "/",
      component: "./component/Home.vue"
    },
    {
      name: "contact-us",
      path: "/contact-us",
      component: "./component/ContactUs.vue"
    }
  ]
});
```

**ATTEMPT**

I tried to execute this file:

```
// test.js

import router from "./src/js/router.js";
```

Using node:

```sh
node --experimental-modules test.js
```

But I ran into this error:

> $ node --experimental-modules test.js
>   (node:13688) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\extract-routes-from-vue-router\test.js:1
>   (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import router from > "./src/js/router.js";
>                                                                       ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>      at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
>      at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
>      at Proxy.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
>      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>      at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>      at createDynamicModule (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:73:15)
>      at Object.meta.done (internal/modules/esm/create_dynamic_module.js:42:9)

**QUESTION**

How can I extract only the `path` keys from the router? I would like to generate a sitemap based on my router routes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on this [site](https://zigamiklic.com/simple-sitemap-for-vue-router/) to get all routes as an array of links:

> ```
> const router = new Router({ /* Your Router config go here */ });
>
> function getRoutesList(routes, pre) {
>   return routes.reduce((array, route) => {
>     const path = `${pre}${route.path}`;
>
>     if (route.path !== '*') {
>       array.push(path);
>     }
>
>     if (route.children) {
>       array.push(...getRoutesList(route.children, `${path}/`));
>     }
>
>     return array;
>   }, []);
> }
>
> getRoutesList(router.options.routes, 'https://zigamiklic.com');
> ```
>
> Example output:
>
> ```
> [
>    'https://zigamiklic.com/home',
>    'https://zigamiklic.com/settings/',
>    'https://zigamiklic.com/settings/general',
>    'https://zigamiklic.com/settings/profile',
>    'https://zigamiklic.com/contact',
> ]
> ```

If you don't need the prefix, you could use it like this:

```
getRoutesList(router.options.routes, '');
```